# ¿Agregar template popover a un span?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Este es el código que encontré para agregar un diseño del template al popover pero al ingresarlo desde el javascript no lo muestra

```
$(this).append('<span  class="badge badge-pill label-warning"  style="font-size: 12px;color:white" >' + count + '</span>');
$(this).find("span").popover({ template: '<div class="popover" role="tooltip"><div class="arrow"></div><h3 class="popover-header">Prueba</h3><div class="popover-body">Prueba</div></div>' });
```

Comment: ¿Estas usando Bootstrap?

Comment: si es la version 4.3

Comment: ¿Podrias intentar [crear un ejemplo minimo y verificable](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)?